# Gali (2015) Chapter 8 Symmetric Steady State

Tags: macroeconomics, open-economy-macro

In Chapter 8 (small open economy) of Gali's 2015 version of Monetary Policy, Inflation, and the Business Cycle, he often performs log linearisations around a symmetric steady state like below:

[image]

My questions are:
1. What exactly is a symmetric steady state,
2. How do we know that it exists
3. How do we know that $P_H = P_F = P$ in steady state? (I know from S=1, that I can infer that $P_H = P_F$, but I'm confused about whether S=1 is the **cause** for $P_H = P_F$ or a **consequence** of $P_H = P_F$).

Thank you very much for your time in advance!

Answer (score 2):

1. The steady state is "symmetric" in the sense that terms of trade with *all* other countries are equal to $1$, with respect to the home country. It would be non-symmetric if for some of them terms of trade were not equal to unity.
2. Is there anything in the model that *precludes* this steady state from existing? Usually not. Then it is feasible, i.e. it exists. Whether it is an *attractive*, *stable* steady state, is another matter.
3. $S$ is the ratio of two price levels. Logically then, it is a derivative measure of these two, so the price levels are the underlying forces.

Answer (score 0):

There is a symmetric steady state when there is absence of the international financial market or when markets are complete. Did you find any other explanation?